# Solving integer network flow problem using OptaPlanner

Tags: optaplanner, optapy

I am new to OptaPlanner and would like to test its capabilities on an integer network flow problem.

The problem I am trying to model is relatively simple:

- We are given a directed graph with nodes and edges (where edges are (node from, node to) pairs).
- All nodes and edges have lower bounds and upper bounds on flows, and per-unit flow costs.
- All node and edge flows are integer.
- Constraints:

  - Flow bounds: both node and edge flows must be between their respective lower and upper bounds (hard penalty),
  - Flow conservation: for every non-source and non-sink node, the total in-flow must equal the total out-flow (hard penalty).
  - Cost minimization: we wish to minimize the per-unit flow cost for both node and edge flows (soft penalty).

I started by modeling the problem facts as follows using OptaPy:

```
from optapy import problem_fact, planning_id

@problem_fact
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id, lb, ub, cost):
        self.id = id
        self.lb = lb
        self.ub = ub
        self.cost = cost

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Node(id={self.id},lb={self.lb},ub={self.ub},cost={self.cost})'

@problem_fact
class Edge:
    def __init__(self, id, node_from, node_to, cost):
        self.id = id
        self.node_from = node_from
        self.node_to = node_to
        self.cost = cost

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Node(id={self.id},node_from={self.node_from.id},node_to={self.node_to.id},cost={self.cost})'
```

I am guessing that the planning entities and variables are done analogously?

```
from optapy import planning_entity, planning_variable

@planning_entity
class NodeFlow:
    def __init__(self, id, node, flow=None):
        self.id = id
        self.node = node
        self.flow = flow

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    @planning_variable(Node, ['nodeFlowRange'])
    def get_flow(self):
        return self.flow

    def set_flow(self, new_flow):
        self.flow = new_flow

@planning_entity
class EdgeFlow:
    def __init__(self, id, edge, flow=None):
        self.id = id
        self.edge = edge
        self.flow = flow

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    @planning_variable(Node, ['edgeFlowRange'])
    def get_flow(self):
        return self.flow

    def set_flow(self, new_flow):
        self.flow = new_flow
```

However, now I am stuck modeling the constraints. It's not clear to me how to model, e.g., flow conservation. My code skeleton is as follows:

```
from optapy import constraint_provider
from optapy.types import Joiners, HardSoftScore

@constraint_provider
def define_constraints(constraint_factory):
    return [
        # Hard constraints
        flow_conservation(constraint_factory)
    ]

def flow_conservation(constraint_factory):
    return constraint_factory \
        .for_each(Node) \
        #.group_by(?) # To sum in-flows and out-flows per node?
        .join(Node,
              # ?
              ) \
        .penalize('Flow conservation conflict', HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
```

Is this the correct way to model such a problem?
How do I model e.g. flow conservation?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"flow_bounds" can be modelled as a "built-in" constraint by using "@value_range_provider" on a "@planning_entity" (as described in https://www.optapy.org/docs/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#valueRangeProviderOnPlanningEntity), but it appears there is a bug I need to fix with `@value_range_provider` on `@planning_entity`) (will add how to do it once a build with the fix is released).

Since "flow_conservation" only apply to non_sources/non_sinks, I recommend adding a kind field to `Node` to determine if it a source or sink (or just a normal node). From your `NodeFlow` and `EdgeFlow` classes, `flow` is declared to be a `Node`,
but from your problem description, it should be an integer. I am confused
what `NodeFlow` represent (is it `outgoing - incoming` for a given and hence should always be 0 except for `source` and `sink` nodes)?

"cost_minimization" can be split into `node_cost_minimization` and `edge_cost_minimization`, which sums the product `item.flow * item.cost` and penalize by it. Putting all the constraints together, it should look something like this:

```
from optapy import constraint_provider
from optapy.constraint import Joiners, ConstraintCollectors
from optapy.score import HardSoftScore
from domain import Node, Edge, NodeFlow, EdgeFlow

@constraint_provider
def flow_constraints(constraint_factory):
    return [
        flow_conservation(constraint_factory),
        minimize_node_cost(constraint_factory),
        minimize_edge_cost(constraint_factory),
        outgoing_bounds(constraint_factory),
        incoming_bounds(constraint_factory),
    ]


def outgoing_bounds(constraint_factory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Node)
             # Join with outgoing edge flows
             .join(EdgeFlow, Joiners.equal(lambda node: node.id, lambda edge_flow: edge_flow.edge.node_from.id))
             # Get total outgoing flow
             .group_by(lambda node, outgoing_edge: node,
                       ConstraintCollectors.sum(lambda node, outgoing_edge: outgoing_edge.flow))
             # Only penalize if outgoing_flow is not in bounds for node
             .filter(lambda node, outgoing_flow: outgoing_flow < node.lb or outgoing_flow > node.ub)
             .penalize('source_bounds', HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, lambda node, outgoing_flow: 1000 * max(node.lb - outgoing_flow, outgoing_flow - node.ub))
    )


def incoming_bounds(constraint_factory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Node)
             # Join with incoming edge flows
             .join(EdgeFlow, Joiners.equal(lambda node: node.id,
                                           lambda edge_flow: edge_flow.edge.node_to.id))
             # Get total incoming flow
             .group_by(lambda node, incoming_edge: node,
                       ConstraintCollectors.sum(lambda node, incoming_edge: incoming_edge.flow))
             # Only penalize if outgoing_flow is not in bounds for node
             .filter(lambda node, incoming_flow: incoming_flow < node.lb or incoming_flow > node.ub)
             .penalize('sink_bounds', HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, lambda node, incoming_flow: 1000 * max(node.lb - incoming_flow, incoming_flow - node.ub))
    )


def flow_conservation(constraint_factory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Node)
             # Do not include source and sink nodes
             .filter(lambda node: node.kind != 'source' and node.kind != 'sink')
             # Join with incoming edge flows
             .join(EdgeFlow, Joiners.equal(lambda node: node.id,
                                           lambda edge_flow: edge_flow.edge.node_from.id))
             # Get total incoming flow
             .group_by(lambda node, incoming_edge: node,
                       ConstraintCollectors.sum(lambda node, incoming_edge: incoming_edge.flow))
             # Join with outgoing edge flows
             .join(EdgeFlow, Joiners.equal(lambda node, incoming_flow: node.id,
                                           lambda edge_flow: edge_flow.edge.node_to.id))
             # Get total outgoing flow
             .group_by(lambda node, incoming_flow, outgoing_edge: node,
                       lambda node, incoming_flow, outgoing_edge: incoming_flow,
                       ConstraintCollectors.sum(lambda node, incoming_flow, outgoing_edge: outgoing_edge.flow))
             # Only penalize if incoming flow != outgoing flow
             .filter(lambda node, incoming_flow, outgoing_flow: incoming_flow != outgoing_flow)
             .penalize('flow_conservation', HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD, lambda node, incoming_flow, outgoing_flow: abs(incoming_flow - outgoing_flow))
    )


def minimize_node_cost(constraint_factory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(NodeFlow)
            .group_by(ConstraintCollectors.sum(lambda node_flow: node_flow.node.cost * node_flow.flow))
            .penalize('node flow cost', HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, lambda cost: cost)
    )


def minimize_edge_cost(constraint_factory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(EdgeFlow)
            .group_by(ConstraintCollectors.sum(lambda edge_flow: edge_flow.edge.cost * edge_flow.flow))
            .penalize('edge flow cost', HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, lambda cost: cost)
    )
```

The domain objects I used:

```
from optapy import problem_fact, planning_id


@problem_fact
class Node:
    def __init__(self, id, lb, ub, cost, kind):
        self.id = id
        self.lb = lb
        self.ub = ub
        self.kind = kind
        self.cost = cost

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Node(id={self.id},lb={self.lb},ub={self.ub},cost={self.cost})'


@problem_fact
class Edge:
    def __init__(self, id, node_from, node_to, lb, ub, cost):
        self.id = id
        self.node_from = node_from
        self.node_to = node_to
        self.lb = lb
        self.ub = ub
        self.cost = cost

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Node(id={self.id},node_from={self.node_from.id},node_to={self.node_to.id},cost={self.cost})'


from optapy import planning_entity, planning_variable, planning_solution, planning_score, \
planning_entity_collection_property, problem_fact_collection_property, value_range_provider

from optapy.score import HardSoftScore


@planning_entity
class NodeFlow:
    def __init__(self, id, node, flow=None):
        self.id = id
        self.node = node
        self.flow = flow

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    @planning_variable(object, ['nodeFlowRange'])
    def get_flow(self):
        return self.flow

    def set_flow(self, new_flow):
        self.flow = new_flow

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.node}: {self.flow}'



@planning_entity
class EdgeFlow:
    def __init__(self, id, edge, flow=None):
        self.id = id
        self.edge = edge
        self.flow = flow

    @planning_id
    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    @planning_variable(int, ['edgeFlowRange'])
    def get_flow(self):
        return self.flow

    def set_flow(self, new_flow):
        self.flow = new_flow

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.edge}: {self.flow}'



@planning_solution
class NetworkFlow:
    def __init__(self, nodes, edges, node_flows, edge_flows, score):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.edges = edges
        self.node_flows = node_flows
        self.edge_flows = edge_flows
        self.score = score

    @problem_fact_collection_property(Node)
    def get_nodes(self):
        return self.nodes

    @problem_fact_collection_property(Edge)
    def get_edges(self):
        return self.edges

    @planning_entity_collection_property(NodeFlow)
    def get_node_flows(self):
        return self.node_flows

    @planning_entity_collection_property(EdgeFlow)
    def get_edge_flows(self):
        return self.edge_flows

    @planning_score(HardSoftScore)
    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

    @problem_fact_collection_property(int)
    @value_range_provider('edgeFlowRange')
    def get_edge_flow_range(self):
        if len(self.edges) == 0:
            return [0]
        else:
            lb = min(map(lambda edge: edge.lb, self.edges))
            ub = max(map(lambda edge: edge.ub, self.edges))
            return [i for i in range(lb, ub + 1)]

    @problem_fact_collection_property(int)
    @value_range_provider('nodeFlowRange')
    def get_node_flow_range(self):
        if len(self.nodes) == 0:
            return [0]
        else:
            lb = min(map(lambda node: node.lb, self.nodes))
            ub = max(map(lambda node: node.ub, self.nodes))
            return [i for i in range(lb, ub + 1)]

    def set_score(self, score):
        self.score = score

    def __str__(self):
        return (f'Nodes:\n' +
                f'\n'.join(list(map(str, self.node_flows))) +
                f'\nEdges:\n' +
                f'\n'.join(list(map(str, self.edge_flows))) +
                f'\nScore: {self.score}'
        )


def generate_problem():
    nodes = [
        Node('source', 10, 10, 1, 'source'),
        Node('sink', 10, 10, 1, 'sink'),
        Node('a', 0, 2, 1, 'node'),
        Node('b', 0, 8, 2, 'node'),
        Node('c', 0, 3, 1, 'node'),
    ]
    edges = [
        Edge('source-a', nodes[0], nodes[2], 0, 2, 1),
        Edge('source-b', nodes[0], nodes[3], 0, 10, 2),
        Edge('b-c', nodes[3], nodes[4], 0, 3, 1),
        Edge('a-sink', nodes[2], nodes[1], 0, 2, 1),
        Edge('b-sink', nodes[3], nodes[1], 0, 5, 2),
        Edge('c-sink', nodes[4], nodes[1], 0, 3, 1),
    ]
    node_flows = []
    edge_flows = list(map(lambda edge: EdgeFlow(edge.id, edge), edges))
    return NetworkFlow(nodes, edges, node_flows, edge_flows, None)
```

It can be simpler (for instance, you can put the planning variable "flow" directly into `Node` and `Edge` and remove `NodeFlow` and `EdgeFlow`). Do note OptaPy is significantly slower than OptaPlanner currently, but we are working on improving its performance (hopefully in the next release).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, @christopher-chianelli - this is fantastic! As a follow-up, I noticed that the value_range_providers return the same value ranges for every NodeFlow/EdgeFlow variable - is this a requirement for OptaPlanner or can planning_variables have individual value ranges?

Thank you also for pointing out the performance loss due to OptaPy - I will try out OptaPlanner in native Java next.

Comment: planning variables can have individual values ranges (which I eluded to with https://www.optapy.org/docs/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#valueRangeProviderOnPlanningEntity ), but when I was testing it out, it appears OptaPy errors when the `@value_range_provider` is on a `@planning_entity` and does not return a list of `@problem_facts` (this work fine in OptaPlanner). I will fix the bug after the performance work is finished (which will bring OptaPy performance a lot closer to OptaPlanner performance, but still slower).

Comment: Thank you! I'll move things to native Java to try out individual value ranges (and check the performance boost). Thanks again for your help!